# How to choose between singular/plural verb in multiple sentences

Tags: grammar, verbs, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

From my personal standpoint; following trends, trying to understand even little bits of what’s happening around you and the world, reaching out to people, putting yourself in their shoes **is** crucial in a data-driven time like this and **requires** creative and brand new strategies.

In this paragraph, should I use the singular or plural form of the verb?

Comment: Can you work out what the structure of the sentence is meant to be: is "putting yourself in their shoes" or "reaching out to people" meant to be the subject of the latter part of the sentence? Is the other phrase a description or modifier of the subject? Or do you mean "putting yourself in their shoes and reaching out to people" in combination? To work out if a noun should be single or plural you need to identify its subject.

Comment: Actually, 
following trends [item 1]
trying to understand even little bits of what's happening around you and the world [item 2]
reaching out to people [item 3]
putting yourself in their shoes [item 4]

They are all crucial and all require creative and brand new strategies.

Maybe the way I build this sentence is wrong, do you have any suggestions regarding that? Thank you.